# How can I inline the receiver parameter of an extension function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, inline, extension-function

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52057360/3755692), I was thinking about how could one inline the receiver parameter of an extension function? In theory, like this:

```
inline fun <T> not(crossinline predicate : (T) -> Boolean)
    = { e : T -> !predicate(e) }
```

Just that `predicate` becomes our receiver function:

```
operator inline fun <T> ((T) -> Boolean).not()
    = { e : T -> !this(e) }
```

Now, for the above code, I'd expect the compiler to complain that it needs `crossinline`; however, I get the following warning:

> Warning: Expected performance impact of inlining `public inline operator fun <T> ((T) -> Boolean).not(): (T) -> Boolean` is insignificant. Inlining works best for functions with parameters of functional types

This lets me believe that the compiler is not inlining the receiver of that function. Adding `inline` or `crossinline` only produces syntax errors.

Not being able to inline the second function decreases the performance over the first one.

Is there any way to tell the compiler to inline that receiver parameter?

Comment: initially I just wanted to answer that only functions with lambda parameters are inlined... however as, at least in Java, both functions are actually becoming static methods under the hood and probably just look the same, I would have expected the same too... that a `crossinline` is also possible on the second... but maybe that's only the case for Java and in other languages this isn't the case?

Comment: @Roland Inlining is not supported by the java compiler. If a function is marked as `inline`, it's lambda parameters are only inlined when you call it from Kotlin with a lambda that the compiler can inline. However, the _receiver parameter_ is a parameter with special syntax and special treatment, but I don't see a reason why the compiler couldn't inline it

Comment: I know... I rather meant what the extension function will translate too... it's basically just the same... That's also the reason why you will get a JVM name clash if you implement both methods.

Comment: @Roland You are right, both translate to `public static final <T> kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1<T, java.lang.Boolean> not(kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1<? super T, java.lang.Boolean>);`. However this doesn't really matter as the translated jvm signature has no inlining information at all (and don't forget kotlin can also be compiled to javascript)

Comment: Yeah... I think my English is not as good as I hoped it to be (or I am too tired) ;-) regarding the other languages, e.g. javascript: I tried to say that in the first comment... obviously, the comment didn't arrive. :-)

Comment: what I wanted to say: on the JVM they look the same so I would have expected that they are also considered the same on Kotlin... but maybe due to the support for other languages this isn't the case... maybe now it's clearer what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is tracked in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5837, but doesn't seem to be actively worked on :( I actually [just suggested supporting `noinline`/`crossinline`](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-30398) hoping that's the main reason receiver isn't inlined.